# LRTHWx46, what does "mkdir bin data doc ext lib tests lib/NAME" do? I can't reason my way to a solution if I don't know the intended result

Tags: ruby, command-line, command, helper

I have literally no idea what I'm supposed to accomplish with the given directions. It says that if I follow them a skeleton will be made. But I'm at a computer terminal, not a dna 3d printer, so I am not looking to build a skeleton. I'm looking to build this thing the book calls a skeleton and I have no clue how to tell if I correctly complied. Please help. The command I need to understand is "mkdir bin data doc ext lib tests lib/NAME".

Comment: That is a fairly standard linux/unix command for creating directories. Try `mkdir --help` or `man mkdir` for more information about the `mkdir` command.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. Your question isn't a good fit for SO as it's about general computing. SO is for coding problems. "[su]" would be a more appropriate site.

Answer (score 2):

`mkdir` is the Unix command to make a directory.   The specific command you mentioned will create directories named "bin", "data", "doc", "ext", "lib", and "tests" in the current directory, and a directory "NAME" under the newly-created "lib" directory.  This is a typical directory structure for organizing a programming project (or, as your book puts it, a "skeleton" structure).